# Azure Bot Framework: Bot responds with “undefined” (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, facebook, azure, botframework, middleware

My bot is used in a way whereby when user types a question, it will redirect the dialog and return an answer based on the question. Currently, I am trying to store the conversation history. Adding middleware is part of process for storing and I faced an issue whereby "**undefined**" unexpectedly appears in the message log.

**My code snippet**

```
bot.dialog('cards', [
  function (session) {

    session.send('Test1');
    var msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
        .textFormat(builder.TextFormat.xml)
        .attachments([
          new builder.HeroCard(session)
                .title('Test1')
                .images([
                  builder.CardImage.create(session, 'imgURL')
                ])
                .buttons([builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, 'Card1', null, 'Here')
                  ])
        ]);
        msg.addAttachment (
            new builder.HeroCard(session)
                .title("Test2")
                .images([
                    builder.CardImage.create(session, "imgUrl")
                ])
                .buttons([
                    builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, "Card2", null, "Here")
                ])
        );

    session.endDialog(msg)
  }
]).triggerAction({
matches: 'Greetings'})

//Adding of new card
bot.dialog('Card1', [
  function (session) {
    var msg1 = new builder.Message(session).sourceEvent({
    //specify the channel
    facebook: {
      text:"Card1"
    }
  });

    session.endDialog(msg1)
    session.beginDialog('card1link');
  }
]).triggerAction({
matches: 'card1'})

bot.dialog('card1link', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, '1. Card2\n2. Card3\n', ['1', '2'], {
            retryPrompt: "Please pick your choice.\n1. Card2\n2. Card3\n",
            maxRetries: 1
        });
    },
    function (session, args, next) {
        if (args.response) {
            var choice = args.response.entity;
            switch (choice) {
                case '1':
                    session.replaceDialog('Card2');
                    break;
                case '2':
                    session.replaceDialog('Card3');
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            session.send("Sorry");
        }
    }
]);
```

**Output**

> (User-to-Bot) message: hi
>
> (Bot-to-User) message: Test1
>
> (Bot-to-User) message: undefined
>
> (User-to-Bot) message: Card1
>
> (Bot-to-User) message: undefined
>
> (Bot-to-User) message: Please pick your choice.
>   1. Card2
>   2. Card3

**Expected**

> (User-to-Bot) message: hi
>
> (Bot-to-User) message: Test1
>
> (User-to-Bot) message: Card1
>
> (Bot-to-User) message: Please pick your choice.
>   1. Card2
>   2. Card3

Comment: Which channel are you seeing this behavior, is this in the test WebChat pane on Azure?

Comment: While I wasn't able to finish the expected steps due to some problems with the routing, copy-pasting your code successfully rendered a carousel in the Emulator.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the Facebook tag. I'm not sure if Facebook supports XML formatting for Rich Cards/[Templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/generic)

Comment: @StevenG. I am able to display the rich cards on FB. Is there way to omit the word "undefined"?

Comment: When is the word "undefined" generated? Right before any cards are shown to the user?

Comment: @StevenG. I realised that the word "undefined" will appears when message (facebook: {
      text:"Card1"
    }) and carousel of cards from the bot is send out.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provide your code snippet in `recieve` or `send` middleware. Assume you are using following code to log history:

```
bot.use({
    receive: (evt, next) => {
        //handle evt
        //what you save should be `evt.text` as the message
        next();
    },
    send: (evt, next) => {
        //handle evt
        //what you save should be `evt.text` as the message
        next();
    }
})
```

When your bot got `(Bot-to-User) message: undefined`, it should triggerred for the `endOfConversation` event. This event has the struct like:

```
{
    address:Object {id: "9n1h124ddkb2", channelId: "emulator", user: Object, …}
    code:"completedSuccessfully"
    textLocale:"en-US"
    type:"endOfConversation"
}
```

Which do not contain `text` propertity.
This should be the criminal.

You can add a condition to avoid this:

```
 receive: (evt, next) => {
        console.log(evt);
        if (evt.type == 'message') {
           your logic here
        }
        next();
    }
```

Comment: @GuessssMe did Gary's answer help? I haven't had the chance to test this, but I am also assuming that the non-existent `text` property is the root cause. Have you tried setting the property on the outgoing message to an empty string: `''`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use synonyms and retryPrompt for this.

```
builder.Prompts.choice(
        session, 
        "Selection one option", 
        [
            {
                value: "1",
                synonyms: ["Card1", "Card 1"]
            },
            {
                value: "2",
                synonyms: ["Card2", "Card 2"]
            }
        ],
        {
            listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button,
            retryPrompt: 'Selection one option.'
        }
    )
```